# Remove last word of string to first word in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a string variable. I want to find a dplyr way to move the words in `trail` from `string` to the beginning of the string and remove it from the end, as in `goal`.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thank you!

```
string <- as.data.frame(c("ABA PRIMARY SCHOOL", "BLABLA SECONDARY SCHOOL", "WAZA INSTITUT", "INSTITUT WAMA", "PRIMARY SCHOOL WAMA"))

trail = c(" PRIMARY SCHOOL", " SECONDARY SCHOOL", " INSTITUT")

goal <- as.data.frame(c("PRIMARY SCHOOL ABA", "SECONDARY SCHOOL BLABLA", "INSTITUT WAZA", "INSTITUT WAMA", "PRIMARY SCHOOL WAMA"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `dplyr` and `stringr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(temp = str_extract(string, str_c(trail, collapse = '|')), 
         result = ifelse(is.na(temp), string, str_c(temp, str_remove(string, temp), sep = ' '))) %>%
  select(-temp)

#                  string                   result
#1      ABA PRIMARY SCHOOL       PRIMARY SCHOOL ABA
#2 BLABLA SECONDARY SCHOOL  SECONDARY SCHOOL BLABLA
#3           WAZA INSTITUT            INSTITUT WAZA
#4           INSTITUT WAMA            INSTITUT WAMA
#5     PRIMARY SCHOOL WAMA      PRIMARY SCHOOL WAMA
```

**data**

```
string <- c("ABA PRIMARY SCHOOL", "BLABLA SECONDARY SCHOOL", "WAZA INSTITUT", "INSTITUT WAMA", "PRIMARY SCHOOL WAMA")
df <- data.frame(string)
trail = c(" PRIMARY SCHOOL", " SECONDARY SCHOOL", " INSTITUT")
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in `base R` with `gsub` and `paste`

```
df$result <- trimws(gsub(paste0("(.*)\\b(", paste(trail, collapse="|"), 
    ")\\b"), "\\2 \\1", df$string))
df$result
[1] "PRIMARY SCHOOL ABA"      "SECONDARY SCHOOL BLABLA" "INSTITUT WAZA"           "INSTITUT WAMA"           "PRIMARY SCHOOL WAMA"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(string = c("ABA PRIMARY SCHOOL", "BLABLA SECONDARY SCHOOL", 
"WAZA INSTITUT", "INSTITUT WAMA", "PRIMARY SCHOOL WAMA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

trail <- c(" PRIMARY SCHOOL", " SECONDARY SCHOOL", " INSTITUT")
```